# Proof that the most general mapping which preserves 2D lines is a linear fractional transformation.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I have read that the most general form of a transformation that maps a straight line into a straight line, both in 2D real planes, is a linear fractional transformation:

X' = (aX+bY+c)/(dX+eY+g)
Y' = (hX+kY+l)/(dX+eY+g),   (where a,b,c,d,e,g.h,k,l are all real constants),

which takes [X,Y] into [X',Y']. Substitution into the equation of a line in the X'Y'-plane and clearing the denominator does lead to an equation of a line in the XY-plane.

What is the formal proof that this is the most general such transformation? 
Can someone outline such a proof or direct me to a (preferably online) reference to such a proof?

Comment: These transformations are usually studied in the complex plane, and are called [Möbius transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation).

Comment: I recognize that. Can you direct me to the proof I am looking (be it in the complex plane) which is applicable to the real plane? That is, is the Mobius mapping the most general which carries lines into lines?

Comment: I think the proofs in the complex plane can be adapted to the real plane through usual 'coordinitification' of a complex number $z=a+ib=(a,b)$.

Comment: OK. Can you direct me to such proofs? My references just give the form of the transformation without any discussion of its derivation or whether it is the most general form. That is, if a transformation maps lines into lines, must it be a Mobius transformation?

Comment: I am not really sure that is the case. One can try though. Do you require anything at all about these transformations? Injectivity (along lines at least), continuity, etc? I believe one can construct a non-Möbius transformation that maps lines to lines if you leave it too open-ended (say, $\lVert z \rVert$).

Comment: The mapping should be one-to-one, continuous, and differentiable.

Comment: I misspoke. The mapping is just one-to-one. Continuity and differentiability are properties I would like it to have. Clearly, a  linear fractional transformation is not continuous along the line (dX+eY+g) in its denominator (unless d=e=0). What concerns me is that if the straight lines that are conserved all pass through the origin then that denominator can be replaced by an arbitrary function f(X,Y). That is why I would like to see the derivation of the mapping.

Comment: Simply from it being one-to-one one can show the map sends parallel lines to parallel lines, but there's still more that needs to be shown...

Comment: Are you referring to a general 1-to-1 map or just the Mobius? The Mobius certainly does this since a translation of coordinates is a Mobius map. As you know the Mobius map is a composite of a translation, a rotation/scaling and an inversion. These three primitive mappings all preserve straight lines (as well as circles). One approach to answering the question I posed is to show that these three maps are the only ones that do this -- or if a mapping preserves straight lines it has to be a composite of these three maps. I haven't been able to show this.

Comment: Any mapping of the plane to itself that preserves lines and is injective must map parallel lines to parallel lines; this is pretty straightforward to show.

Comment: Of course, otherwise the images of the parallel lines would intersect and the mapping would not be injective. But an injective mapping need not map lines into lines.

Comment: I believe I have found a paper which might answer my question. In 1937 Caratheodory proved the following theorem: Every arbitrary one to one correspondence between
the points of a circular disc C and a bounded point set C' by which circles
lying completely in C are transformed into circles lying in C' must always be either
a direct or inverse transformation of Mob

Comment: I don't quite see how this answers your question.

Comment: I not sure it does since I haven't been able to access the reference online. But I expect that proofs in the complex plane are adaptable to the real plane and that infinite radius circles are straight lines should be sufficient.